# a question about work needed to move a charge towards another one

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, coulombs-law

Consider two charges $q_1>0$ &  $q_2>0$ separated by  a distance $d_1$, and we want to move charge $q_2$ to a distance $d_2$ from $d_1$ where $d_1-d_2>0$.

I need to calculate the work needed to do that, so I used the formula:
$$dw=\vec{F}\cdot \vec{dx}$$ 
which implies that $dw=F\cdot dx$ since the two vectors have same sense (suppose that $q_1$ is to the leftand $q_2$ is to the right and that $q_1$ is fixed while $q_2$ is movable along the horizontal line joining the two point charges).Our teacher put that $F=q_1 \cdot q_2 \over 4 \pi\epsilon x^2 $
and then he made the integral from $x=d_1$ to $x=d_2-d_1$.

My question (which is confusing me alot) is why did we substitute this $F$ by $q_1 \cdot q_2 \over 4 \pi\epsilon x^2$? Shouldn't this $F$ be substituted by another value which mu

Comment: The question I've linked refers to a gravitational potential not an electrostatic potential, but it's still basically the same question with the same answer.

Comment: no my question is different i am asking about the force F in the expression of dw
what should we substitute instead of it?is it the force done by us to move the charge or is it the total force done on the charge during displacement?

Comment: I'm not fully sure what your question is, but I think you are misunderstanding what "work needed" means here. The "work needed" is intended to mean the *minimal work* you have to put in, which is the potential difference between $d_2$ and $d_1$, which in turn is by definition the integral of the electrostatic force. This is indeeed the same confusion as in the question JohnRennie linked.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

We assume $q_2$ does not accelerate, so the *net* force on it is zero while it is moving.  The "extra" forces needed to get it going and to stop it at the end cancel each other out upon integration.

Answer (score 0):

The electrostatic force is indeed

$$F = \frac{q_1\cdot q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

Now we need to move the two charges closer to each other - so we are doing work against this force.

Indeed, there is an initial force needed to accelerate the particle (start the motion); however, assuming that the particle comes to rest again when it gets to $d_2$, then we "get that work back".

This is the fundamental concept behind a conservative force: no matter how you get from $A$ to $B$, the work done is always the same. Of course, if you get to $B$ and you have a certain kinetic energy (different than the energy you had when you left $A$) then that requires additional work.

But the work done *against the field* requires you to know just the force that the field provides. Everything else cancels out.